# How to display dynamically textfields and checkboxes and filling them with database data

Tags: java, mysql

Im making school project, it's survey system, 
Its client/server application using mysql database, 
Server gets data(poll titles) from mysql database and sends it to the client while he connects.
Those titles are being displayed in JComboBox so user can choose which poll he want to answer.
I want to click on poll title in JComboBox and want to display on JPanel questions and available answers linked to chosen poll title, each poll can have diffrent questions count and diffrent answers count, and I want to display those poll questions and answers in Jcomponents:
Questions: I want to display them in JTextFields
Answers: I want to display them in Labels with checkboxes near them so user can select answer he wants
Also I want to have displayed Labels with Question 1 Question 2 etc near questions,
so how to make it dynamically? Please help me
Thank you

Comment: Where are you **exactly** stuck?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have tried adding it statically only atm to test it but it's bad solution. I stucked on displaying it, I'm reading data to combobox and when I click on selected poll I have nothing, maybe you would suggest me how to do it ? add it to some array? I dont know how to exactly solve it

Comment: When the user selects the poll title in the combobox, you can read the ID of that poll and retrieve the data sorted by the question number, and every answer could be sorted by date or by votes, similar to SO :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes but how to put those questions in JTextFields and offered answers in Labels, add checkboxes to answers and display all on JPanel dinamically ?

Comment: you maybe be interested in this article: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/DynaGUI/

Comment: It's not 100% what I'm looking for but anyway thanks for any help. I just want to for each question in database display jtextfield and same with answers

Comment: perhaps an ActionListener would work. when the event is handled you can add a Panel that has the TextFields that you want. being able to see the gui source would help.

Comment: @ShaneKelsey thanks for help but it has been solved already:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using JSF with EJB  for this process?
JSF allows you to create a webpage UI, which is connected to a java beans controller, which is then connected to a controller for your database. Everything is very clear and independed in this model and is specifically designed for these situations. You can see a simple example here :
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_jsf_2_ejb

In case you have to use swing it wont do for you although its something good to know, and its design can help you in other situations.